# Azure Cloud Witness with HTTP proxy

Tags: azure, failovercluster, windows-cluster, exchange-2016, sql-server-2016

Windows Server [Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/deploy-cloud-witness) states:

> #### Proxy considerations with Cloud Witness
>
> Cloud Witness uses HTTPS (default port 443) to establish communication with Azure blob service. Ensure that HTTPS port is accessible via network Proxy.

How do I configure the network proxy on WFCS cluster members for only this feature?  I wish to avoid setting a system-wide proxy setting.

Comment: Do you even need a proxy? Are you not allowing external access?

Comment: I am afraid you can not do this.